# Send a scheduled message in my telegram bot linked to a google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I've built a telegram bot using guidance from this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKSXd_od4Lg&t=348s

Is there any way to edit the sendText function such that I could allow the bot to send a message at a set time?

```html
function sendText(id,text){
  var url = telegramUrl + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + id + "&text=" + text;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You mean sometihng like using a time-driven trigger?

Answer (score 0):

### You can include into your code a call to a [ClockTrigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder)

For this, you need to store the `id` and `text` temporarily in [script properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getScriptProperties()) since you cannot pass parameters to a clock trigger.

Sample:

```js
const props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

function sendText(id,text){
  props.setProperty('id', JSON.stringify(id));
  props.setProperty('text', text);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("fetch")
    .timeBased()
    .after(10 * 60 * 1000)
    .create();
}

function fetch(){
  var id = JSON.parse(props.getProperty('id'));
  va text =  props.getProperty('text');
  var url = telegramUrl + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + id + "&text=" + text;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
}
```